# Connecting admin-on-rest with Rails Api

Tags: admin-on-rest

I'm having a really difficult time connecting admin-on-rest with my rails api. I've  been following the tutorial walk through at https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Tutorial.html but when I point to my localhost is where all the trouble starts.

Response

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "id": 13,
            "name": "Event 1",
            "description": "test"
        },
        {
            "id": 16,
            "name": "Event 2",
            "description": "dsadfa adf asd"
        },
        {
            "id": 17,
            "name": "Event 3",
            "description": "Hey this is a test"
        },
        {
            "id": 18,
            "name": "Some Stuff",
            "description": "Yay, it work"
        },
        {
            "id": 20,
            "name": "Test",
            "description": "asdfs"
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "next_page": null,
        "prev_page": null,
        "total_pages": 1,
        "total_count": 5
    }
}
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { jsonServerRestClient, fetchUtils, Admin, Resource } from 'admin-on-rest';

import apiClient from './apiClient';

import { EventList } from './events';
import { PostList } from './posts';

const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
  if (!options.headers) {
      options.headers = new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json' });
  }
  // add your own headers here
  // options.headers.set('X-Custom-Header', 'foobar');
  return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
}
const restClient = apiClient('http://localhost:5000/admin', httpClient);


const App = () => (
  <Admin title="My Admin" restClient={restClient}>
    <Resource name="events" list={EventList} />
  </Admin>
);

export default App;
```

apiClient.js

```
 import { stringify } from 'query-string';
    import {
  GET_LIST,
  GET_ONE,
  GET_MANY,
  GET_MANY_REFERENCE,
  CREATE,
  UPDATE,
  DELETE,
  fetchJson
} from 'admin-on-rest';

/**
 * Maps admin-on-rest queries to a simple REST API
 *
 * The REST dialect is similar to the one of FakeRest
 * @see https://github.com/marmelab/FakeRest
 * @example
 * GET_LIST     => GET http://my.api.url/posts?sort=['title','ASC']&range=[0, 24]
 * GET_ONE      => GET http://my.api.url/posts/123
 * GET_MANY     => GET http://my.api.url/posts?filter={ids:[123,456,789]}
 * UPDATE       => PUT http://my.api.url/posts/123
 * CREATE       => POST http://my.api.url/posts/123
 * DELETE       => DELETE http://my.api.url/posts/123
 */
export default (apiUrl, httpClient = fetchJson) => {
  /**
   * @param {String} type One of the constants appearing at the top if this file, e.g. 'UPDATE'
   * @param {String} resource Name of the resource to fetch, e.g. 'posts'
   * @param {Object} params The REST request params, depending on the type
   * @returns {Object} { url, options } The HTTP request parameters
   */
  const convertRESTRequestToHTTP = (type, resource, params) => {
    console.log(type)
    console.log(params)
    console.log(params.filter)
    console.log(resource)
    console.log(fetchJson)

    let url = '';
    const options = {};
    switch (type) {
      case GET_LIST: {
        const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
        const { field, order } = params.sort;
        const query = {
          sort: JSON.stringify([field, order]),
          range: JSON.stringify([
            (page - 1) * perPage,
            page * perPage - 1,
          ]),
          filter: JSON.stringify(params.filter),
        };
        url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;
        break;
      }
      case GET_ONE:
        url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`;
        break;
      case GET_MANY: {
        const query = {
          filter: JSON.stringify({ id: params.ids }),
        };
        url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;
        break;
      }
      case GET_MANY_REFERENCE: {
        const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
        const { field, order } = params.sort;
        const query = {
          sort: JSON.stringify([field, order]),
          range: JSON.stringify([
            (page - 1) * perPage,
            page * perPage - 1,
          ]),
          filter: JSON.stringify({
            ...params.filter,
            [params.target]: params.id,
          }),
        };
        url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;
        break;
      }
      case UPDATE:
        url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`;
        options.method = 'PUT';
        options.body = JSON.stringify(params.data);
        break;
      case CREATE:
        url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}`;
        options.method = 'POST';
        options.body = JSON.stringify(params.data);
        break;
      case DELETE:
        url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`;
        options.method = 'DELETE';
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error(`Unsupported fetch action type ${type}`);
    }
    return { url, options };
  };

  /**
   * @param {Object} response HTTP response from fetch()
   * @param {String} type One of the constants appearing at the top if this file, e.g. 'UPDATE'
   * @param {String} resource Name of the resource to fetch, e.g. 'posts'
   * @param {Object} params The REST request params, depending on the type
   * @returns {Object} REST response
   */
  const convertHTTPResponseToREST = (response, type, resource, params) => {
    const { headers, json } = response;
    switch (type) {
      case GET_LIST:
      case GET_MANY_REFERENCE:
        // if (!headers.has('content-range')) {
        //   throw new Error(
        //     'The Content-Range header is missing in the HTTP Response. The simple REST client expects responses for lists of resources to contain this header with the total number of results to build the pagination. If you are using CORS, did you declare Content-Range in the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header?'
        //   );
        // }
        console.log("DATA", json[resource])
        return {
          data: json[resource],
          total: json.meta.total_count
        };
      case CREATE:
        return { data: { ...params.data, id: json.id } };
      default:
        return { data: json };
    }
  };

  /**
   * @param {string} type Request type, e.g GET_LIST
   * @param {string} resource Resource name, e.g. "posts"
   * @param {Object} payload Request parameters. Depends on the request type
   * @returns {Promise} the Promise for a REST response
   */
  return (type, resource, params) => {
    const { url, options } = convertRESTRequestToHTTP(
      type,
      resource,
      params
    );
    return httpClient(url, options).then(response =>{
      console.log("RESPONSE", response);
      convertHTTPResponseToREST(response, type, resource, params)}
    );
  };
};
```

events.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { List, Datagrid, Edit, Create, SimpleForm, DateField, ImageField, ReferenceField, translate,
  TextField, EditButton, DisabledInput, TextInput, LongTextInput, DateInput, Show, Tab, TabbedShowLayout } from 'admin-on-rest';

export EventIcon from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/today';
const EventTitle = translate(({ record, translate }) => (
  <span>
    {record ? translate('event.edit.name', { title: record.name }) : ''}
  </span>
));

export const EventList = (props) => (
  <List {...props}>
    <Datagrid>
      <TextField source="id" />
      <TextField source="name" />
      <TextField source="description" />
      <DateField source="date" />
      <ImageField source="flyer" />
      <EditButton basePath="/events" />
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
);
```

The error i receive current is `Cannot read property 'data' of undefined` but I can verify through my logs that the data is being received correctly.

Comment: Cannot read property data of undefined in AOR usually happens when a component is being connected to state somewhere. Have you misspelled some resource name somewhere?

Comment: Its possible but I don't think so

Comment: The other place where your code is looking for the data key is in the rest client above. I would suggest logging through the code and seeing if params is undefined somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `data` as the root level key in your json response.  Change `events` to `data`, for example:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
        "id": 13,
        "name": "Event 1",
        "description": "test"
    },
    {
        "id": 16,
        "name": "Event 2",
        "description": "dsadfa adf asd"
    }
  ],
  "meta": {...}
}
```